# Consul Connect Upstream Interfaces in Docker Containers

Tags: docker, consul, nomad

is it possible to bind consul connect upstreams to another interface besides `127.0.0.1` loopback?

[Consul Connect - Nomad](https://www.consul.io/docs/connect/platform/nomad.html) This article says you can run the connect proxy within the official Docker container but then there is an issue where the upstream dependencies can't be exposed. Running the `raw_exec` version I see the upstreams available on the host machine 127.0.0.1. But if i run the same config within a container other containers can't connect to those ports.

Example configuration:

```
    task "proxy" {
      driver = "docker"

      config {
        image = "consul:1.4.0"
        force_pull = true
        network_mode = "host"

        args = [
          "connect", "proxy",
          "-service", "api",
          "-log-level", "debug",
          "-upstream", "upstream:${NOMAD_PORT_tcp}"
        ]
      }

      env {
        "CONSUL_HTTP_ADDR" = "${NOMAD_IP_tcp}:8500"
      }

      resources {
        network {
          port "tcp" {}
        }
      }
    }
```

In this configuration the service called upstream is only available if you `sh` into the container itself and check with `netcat`. Is there a way to force Consul Connect to bind the upstream service to `0.0.0.0` so it can be exposed on the local Docker network?

Answer (score 1):

The trick here was to use `network_mode = "host"` for both the sidecar container and any other containers that want to utilize the sidecar. The host Docker network makes this possible:

```
"RABBITMQ_HOST" = "localhost"
"RABBITMQ_PORT" = "${NOMAD_PORT_proxy_rabbitmq}"
```

since the Consul Connect sidecar is binding all upstreams to `localhost` and the Docker `host` network exposes all ports within a container as if the container was running as a raw process on the host machine.